# Во время тестирования возникает ошибка связи с БД

Tags: php, yii2, testng, codeception

Проект на YII2. Тестируются роли, все по отдельности проходят тест нормально и по две тоже, но когда они тестируются все разом, на третьей роли тест выдает следующую ошибку:

```
    Scenario Steps:

 1071. $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200) at tests/functional/RoleCest.php:60
 1070. $I->amOnRoute("/catalog/catalog/index") at tests/functional/RoleCest.php:48
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getDb() on null in /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php:135
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php(382): yii\db\ActiveRecord::getDb()
#1 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php(418): yii\db\ActiveRecord::getTableSchema()
#2 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php(492): yii\db\ActiveRecord->attributes()
#3 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php(289): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->hasAttribute('__mocked')
#4 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php(335): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->__get('__mocked')
#5 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Step.php(176): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->__isset('__mocked')
#6 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Step.php(164): Codeception\Step->getC in /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php on line 135



FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getDb() on null in /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php:135
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php(382): yii\db\ActiveRecord::getDb()
#1 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php(418): yii\db\ActiveRecord::getTableSchema()
#2 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php(492): yii\db\ActiveRecord->attributes()
#3 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php(289): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->hasAttribute('__mocked')
#4 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php(335): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->__get('__mocked')
#5 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Step.php(176): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->__isset('__mocked')
#6 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Step.php(164): Codeception\Step->getC 
in /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php:135
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function has() on null in /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php:91
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(262): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException))
#1 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/site.info/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php on line 91
```

Думали, что проблема в используемой памяти, так как всегда ошибка возникала в месте, где отображалась используемая тестом память в 68 мегабайт, с какой бы роли не стартовали. Подняли все лимиты в php.ini FPM, codeception.yml, php.ini CLI, но это видимо не та проблема. Подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку не знаю всей подноготной, смею указать, что подобные срывы БД могут происходить, если дело касается многопоточности. Если да, то вам нужно в каждом выполняемом потоке насильно перезапустить БД. Как это сделать нагуглте, или вечером после работы посмотрю, поищу у себя

V2.0 В тестировании вроде как напрямую БД не используется, а вместо этого пишутся mockup данные, аналогичные записи в таблице

Comment: Тест построен так - достаются все роли из БД, и по каждой отдельной роли идет проверка доступности по всем роутам на сайте, а потом результаты сверяются с пермишшенами для каждой роли. Роли тестируются последовательно.

Comment: @JohnRoget AccessControl вам в помощь. Настройте корректно дотупы, и не страдайте такими тестами)

Comment: Дело в том, что это по факту легаси код и его тестирование уже выявило кучу косяков, хочется все таки довести дело до конца, так как вылезают неожиданные вещи в неожиданных местах. А роли работают вроде, просто тест должен быть какой-никакой.